# Wiring and other questions about installing a heater in workshop

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, garage, heater

I picked up a small construction heater (240v, 4800W) from a garage sale that I’m intending use as a heater in small work area within my garage. Some of the details:

The garage/work area are not attached to the house and are about 40 feet from the house.

The garage is 23’x 40’

The work area is 23’x 10’ (this is the area I will be heating).

The panel is 100 amp (picture below).

The outlet will be about 8’ from the panel.

The heater is 240v, 4800w construction heater (picture below).

From what I understand I can use:
10 gauge, 2 wire with ground will be good. (Maybe do a 3 wire to provide for future use if needed) with a 30 amp breaker.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Are the wire/breaker I mention sufficient?
2. I’ve read somewhere about additional code considerations when adding a heater to an unattached garage. Is there anything I need to consider for this?

First picture is the panel in the garage.

Second picture is the plug and name plate of heater.
Thanks!
[image: Existing panel in garage]

[image: Plug and identifying plate of heater]

Comment: is that a picture of the main service panel in the house? And you need to run a new 240v circuit to the detached garage?

Answer (score 3):

At 4800w 240v #10 and 30 amp breaker is the way to go.

There are no issues under the NEC for a hard wired heater.

To me that looks like a stab lock buss. Or federal pacific but the breakers are different than what I have worked on in the past. I would recommend in doing some research on FPE as double pole breakers are at a huge risk.
I will not work on FPE other than to remove them due to the liability.

If your heater is going to be plugged in depending on jurisdiction you may need a GFCI circuit breaker.

I would recommend doing some research on your panel if a normal panel and hard wired your plan is good to go, no GFCI required.

Comment: Thanks for the info on FPE. I checked it out and the panel and breakers are Federal Pioneer (Canadian version of Federal Pacific).  I checked out the articles on the web regarding this, and ya, it looks bad for this product.  It’s odd though that the  CPSC stopped their investigation. Or is it that this controversy is driven by Dr Aronstein. And why would they still be for sale?? (I guess those are questions for another thread, which I’m sure have already been discussed!). I’ve got more research to do, but it looks like I might replace that panel.

Answer (score -2):

I would use #8 wire, 30 amp breaker. you can use 10, but if the line from the main panel to the garage sub panel is long, then there is a chance to overheat the #10 wire. for such a short run, buy #8.

Comment: Why number 8 the draw is only 20 amps ? Even at 50’ I would only use #10.

Comment: OP stated "The outlet will be about **8’** from the panel."

Comment: Wire doesn't overheat from being long.  For instance a wire 4 times as long might have 4 times the voltage drop and thus emit 4 times the heat, but it's emitting it over 4 times the length, so the heat per length unit is the same regardless of length.   See how that works?  The only issue on the table is the wasted energy, however, you have to consider the price of wire vs the cost of that energy.